# Is a ring intermediate formed in hydroboration?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, molecular-orbital-theory, stability

> [image]
>   This was the mechanism taught to us for hydro-boration

- Something really strange in that mechanism is that in step 2  hydrogen has two bonds.
- Also , the  the doubly bonded $\ce{H}$ , has one bond $\ce{C-H}$ which contains no electrons

Is this mechanism plausible?

---

In clayden they have shown the cleavge of $\ce{H-B}$ bond  and formation of the $\ce{H-C}$ bond in the same step. 
 
But it doesn't mention the formation of a ring anywhere.
[image]

---

Section 1
Let's assume that the ring does form but after cleaning the $\ce{H-B}$ the electron pair goes into the bonding orbital of H not the anti bonding molecular orbital between $\ce{C-H}$ .

---

Primarily my doubts  are

1. The bond with no electron in it (does it actually form)
2. The reasoning in section 1 (the previous section).

Comment: "Something really strange in that mechanism is that in step 2 hydrogen has two bonds." I'll have to check, but that's probably a transition state (not an intermediate), and one of those two solid lines should be a dashed line, indicating a bond being formed/broken.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That should be a transition state, not an intermediate.

[image: hydroboration of propene]

Also, there should not be a positive charge on your boron in the final compound you drew.